# Convert string to date in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table in which there is a column named `period_start` which is type of nvarchar.
And it has different types of date formats.

Ex.

```
 1. 01122018 --ddmmyyyy

 2. 01132018 --mmddyyyy

 3. 20181802 --yyyyddmm

 4. 20180214 --yyyymmdd

 5. 2018-01-02--yyyy-mm-dd

 6. 01/02/2018 --dd-mm-yyyy

 7. 010218 --ddmmyy
```

These are the dates which i want to convert in database date format.

I tried writing this code but wasn't successful.

```
Create Function dbo.[ConvStrToDate]
(@str nvarchar(50))
Returns Date
As
Begin
Declare @ConvertedDate Date;
Set @str = convert(date,@str,104)
Return @ConvertedDate
End
```

Real Data Example..

[image]

Comment: What dates do `20122010` and `10112012`represent?

Comment: So your data has loads of different representations of a date? How do *you* know that `'01122018'` is `01/12/2018` and not `12/01/2018`? Unless you can give us a defined reason as to how to determine this, your task is **impossible**. I'm afraid you are stuck with the poor choice of datatype, and (effectively) your data is completely meaningless.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` might [get you halfway there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e50176c04d28b1f21fc70f2ab92b7dd2), though it doesn't seem to work for all your date patterns.

Comment: @jarlh clearly `'10112012'` is the 12th day, of the 20th month, in the 1011th year. :) What else *could* it be?

Comment: The long term solution is to fix your data at source and not have datetime values represented as strings.

Comment: @Larnu, my birthday, some years ago!

Comment: Hi @Larnu For every date format we a unique code, i have taken distinct of date formats and given in text. I can create a table and assigne date formats to those unique codes. And then can we convert it??

Comment: So, where is that code @ShahabHaidar? Can you post us some real data here please as DDL and DML statements?

Comment: Hi @Larnu For every date format we a unique code, i have taken distinct of date formats and given in text. I can create a table and assigne date formats to those unique codes. And then can we convert it??

Comment: "revert", @ShahabHaidar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for all the examples you've given us, and I've had to utterly guess your design, as you haven't posted that DDL and DML I requested. The [CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation is your friend here, so if you have more styles you haven't supplied, I suggest using that page as a guide to get the results you need.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StringDates (NotDate varchar(12),
                              FormatString varchar(12));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.StringDates (NotDate,
                             FormatString)
VALUES('01122018','ddmmyyyy'),
      ('01132018','mmddyyyy'),
      ('20181802','yyyyddmm'),
      ('20180214','yyyymmdd'),
      ('2018-01-02','yyyy-mm-dd'),
      ('01/02/2018','dd-mm-yyyy'),
      ('010218','ddmmyy');
GO

SELECT CASE FormatString WHEN 'ddmmyyyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(NotDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),103)
                         WHEN 'mmddyyyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(NotDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),101)
                         WHEN 'yyyyddmm' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(LEFT(NotDate,4), RIGHT(NotDate,2),SUBSTRING(NotDate, 5,2)),112)
                         WHEN 'yyyymmdd' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,NotDate,120)
                         WHEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,NotDate,121)
                         WHEN 'dd-mm-yyyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,REPLACE(NotDate,'-','/'),103)
                         WHEN 'ddmmyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(NotDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),3)
       END,
       FormatString
FROM dbo.StringDates
```

There is, however, only one **real** solution here. Fix that data type:

```
UPDATE StringDates
SET NotDate = CONVERT(varchar(8),CASE FormatString WHEN 'ddmmyyyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(NotDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),103)
                                                   WHEN 'mmddyyyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(NotDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),101)
                                                   WHEN 'yyyyddmm' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT(LEFT(NotDate,4), RIGHT(NotDate,2),SUBSTRING(NotDate, 5,2)),112)
                                                   WHEN 'yyyymmdd' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,NotDate,120)
                                                   WHEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,NotDate,121)
                                                   WHEN 'dd-mm-yyyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,REPLACE(NotDate,'-','/'),103)
                                                   WHEN 'ddmmyy' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date, STUFF(STUFF(NotDate,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),3)
                                        END,112);

ALTER TABLE dbo.StringDates ALTER COLUMN NotDate date;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.StringDates;

GO
--clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.StringDates;
```

Comment: Hi @Larnu Thanks a lot for your reply.

It really helps me..

But cant change data type of column, because it is linked with api..that, is why it's data type is nvarchar. basically, customer sends data to API so we have to accept any data and need to change it at our end.

Comment: can i create a function for the same to slecet column with function

Comment: Yes, @ShahabHaidar, you can. I would suggest an inline table-value function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Larnu

I have added an image of real data

Comment: That image looks nothing like the information you have supplied us, @ShahabHaidar. But, images also aren't helpful here. I've made my stab in the dark here, but I'm guessing this doesn't solve the problem you have (but it would solve it based on the information we had before). This should, however, put you on the path to getting the right answer. You're the one that needs to support the solution in the end. Good luck!