# Converting NVARCHAR to SMALLDATETIME on SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

I'm currently working on updating company database in which on one of the tables the `CreateDt` is in the `nvarchar(20)` type and stores dates in the following ways:

```
12 May 12
29/03/2011
9/24/2012
29/01/2001 08:51:56
```

There are 17,000 rows.

So I'm currently working on code in which I will be able to convert these dates all into the one format such as `DD-MM-YYYY`.

However I'm struggling to find anything suitable.

So far I have tried:

```
WITH CreateDt1
AS
(
    SELECT '14 DECEMBER 12' AS CreateDt1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '13/10/2005'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '12/14/2012'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '24/05/2002 09:28:58' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '28/02/2011'
)
SELECT
    CreateDt1,

    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CreateDt1) = 1

    THEN CAST(CreateDt1 AS datetime)

    ELSE 

        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 3, 1) = '/'
        THEN 
            CASE WHEN ISDATE(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1, 2) + '/' + RIGHT (CreateDt1, 4)) = 1
                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1 , 2) + '/' + RIGHT (CreateDt1, 4) AS datetime)
            END
        END
    END AS NewDate
FROM fct_Project;
```

However this returns null values for dates such as `29/01/2001 08:51:56`.

Comment: Very similar to yesterday's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024773/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have edited the question to show what i have used so far

Comment: Your sample data has no tricky dates. Add `11/12/2012` to make things harder.

Comment: You have `13/10` and `12/14` in the data. How do you plan to handle `10/11`? 11th october or 10th november?

Comment: the above code as changed all formats expect 29/01/2001 08:51:56 which i understand to be dd/mm/yyyy and ways in which the script could be altered to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add LEFT function in RIGHT to your query in case clause like:

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(CreateDt1) = 1

THEN CAST(CreateDt1 AS datetime)

ELSE 

    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 3, 1) = '/'
    THEN 
        CASE WHEN ISDATE(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1, 2) + '/' + RIGHT (LEFT(CreateDt1,10), 4)) = 1
            THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1 , 2) + '/' + RIGHT (LEFT(CreateDt1,10), 4) AS datetime)
        END
    END
END AS NewDate
```

Comment: This has sorted it! All dates have now converted your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've just edited your code by adding a few lines, hope it will help. 
Keep in mind, that it does not solve problem of 10/11 and 11/10 cases.

```
WITH CreateDt1
AS
(
    SELECT '14 DECEMBER 12' AS CreateDt1
    UNION ALL
      SELECT '13/10/2005'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '12/14/2012'
      UNION ALL
    SELECT '24/05/2002 09:28:58'  
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '28/02/2011'
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CreateDt1) = 1
         THEN CAST(CreateDt1 AS datetime)
         ELSE 
             CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 3, 1) = '/'
                 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN ISDATE(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1, 2) + '/' + RIGHT (CreateDt1, 4)) = 1
                         THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1 , 2) + '/' + RIGHT (CreateDt1, 4) AS datetime)
                         WHEN ISDATE(SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1, 2) + '/' + LEFT((RIGHT (CreateDt1, 13)),4) ) = 1 
                         THEN CAST ( (SUBSTRING(CreateDt1, 4, 2) + '/' + LEFT(CreateDt1, 2) + '/' + LEFT((RIGHT (CreateDt1, 13)),4) ) AS DATETIME)
                    END
             END


    END AS NewDate
FROM CreateDt1;
```